# changing sprite frame depending on random value

Tags: list, lua, sprite-sheet

I have a list of buttons(currently images) and i want to change the image color depending on the value that is taken from the list

```
buttons = {"btn1","btn2","btn3","btn4"}

local buttonSheetData = {
    width = 150,
    height = 150,
    numFrames = 2,
    sheetContentWidth = 300,
    sheetcontentheight = 150,
}

local buttonSheet = graphics.newImageSheet("image/buttonSS.png", buttonSheetData)

local sequenceData = {
    {name = "black", start = 1, count = 1},
    {name = "red", start = 2, count = 1}
}

local btn1 = display.newSprite(buttonSheet, sequenceData)
btn1.x = 100
btn1.y = 90

local btn2 = display.newSprite(buttonSheet, sequenceData)
btn2.x = 200
btn2.y = 230

local btn3 = display.newSprite(buttonSheet, sequenceData)
btn3.x = 300
btn3.y = 90

local btn4 = display.newSprite(buttonSheet, sequenceData)
btn4.x = 400
btn4.y = 230

x = buttons[math.random(#buttons)] 
x:setFrame(2)
```

The circles are currently black. every time i run the code i want it to take a random value from the list and change the color to red. so there is a different red circle when i run the code

I keep getting the error:
"Attemp to call method 'setSequence' (a nill value)"

Comment: Where is `setSequence` being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're code is treating strings and variable names as if they are interchangeable. The first line:

```
buttons = {"btn1","btn2","btn3","btn4"}
```

creates a table of strings, so the line:

```
x = buttons[math.random(#buttons)]
```

will set `x` to be a random entry of `buttons` which are strings so the next line (`x:setFrame(2)`) is calling a method that doesn't exist on a string.

Instead, create a table of your buttons:

```
buttons = {btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4} -- creates a table of buttons
x = buttons[math.random(#buttons)] -- x is a random entry of buttons (a button)
```